# Total Results versus Returned Results in PHP

Tags: php

I am using the following php to display the number of records **returned** in a db search.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM authorsbooks WHERE author LIKE   '%$searchquery%'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$rows = $row[0];
$textline1 = "Your Search Returned (<b>$rows</b>) Records";
<?php echo $textline1; ?>
```

This seems to work fine.

However, I cannot get the total number of records in the actual db to display.
Can anyone explain a way of getting the total number of records in the database. Btw, I have tried using `$total = mysqli_num_rows($query)` but it keeps returning 1 as an answer.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not use `mysqli_num_rows()` Using query `SELECT id FROM ...`

Comment: mysqli_num_rows will return number of row, so in your case count(id) will return only one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you've to fire another SQL query. Like this,

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM authorsbooks";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$rows = $row[0];
echo $rows; // will return total rows in database.
```

Comment: Ok, thanks Alok, got it and it worked, thanks v.much ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM authorsbooks
```

It's true that `$total = mysqli_num_rows($query)` should return one row. When you do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` then the query returns 1 row telling you how many matches there were in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben ;-)